# Web Service request fails on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am developing an ASP.NET page that consumes a web service. My web application is hosted on iis and i am attaching my project to it. The problem is that when i debug my web service call local (using VS server) everything goes fine, but when i debug my web service call on iis, it fails with a message `"unable to connect to the remote server"`.

Is there any configuration on IIS that blocks web service calls?

Comment: are you sure its connecting to the right place?

Comment: yes, i am using the same address and config. The only different thing i'm doing is to set the debug to local and to iis in the project properties.

Comment: I don't know if it's the best approach to solve the problem, but, after some googling i realized that ASP.NET Impersonation was disable. That was the "solution". Thanks @Daniel A. White for your attention.